# How to change the delete repeating elements in the values of a dictionary , python3?

Tags: python-3.x

An Example:

```
a={2:[2,2,3,5,6,7], 3:[5,5,2,3,7,7,8],...}
```

a is a dict, and I want to delete the repeating elements in the values, and then change the dict as follows:

```
a={2:[2,3,5,6,7], 3:[5,2,3,7,8],...}
```

How to implement?

Comment: instead of list as a value, you can try set? it automatically does not allow duplicated but does not guarantee insert order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, use this list comprehension, which basically converts every list to a set (which removes duplicates automatically), and then convert it back to a list:

```
a = {2:[2,2,3,5,6,7], 3:[5,5,2,3,7,7,8]}

a = {k: list(set(a[k])) for k in a}

print(a) # ==> {2: [2, 3, 5, 6, 7], 3: [2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `set` to remove duplicates

```
a = {2:[2,2,3,5,6,7], 3:[5,5,2,3,7,7,8],...}

# using dict comprehension
a = {key: list(set(value)) for key, value in a.items()}
```

read more about sets: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets